# Designing a many-to-many relationship in Redis

Tags: redis

I have two data types, each with a numeric ID. I want a mapping from one to the other, and I see two obvious ways to do it:

1. A key for each entity of type A, that contains a set of IDs of type B.
2. A single large sorted set that contains ranks that correspond to keys of type A (they can repeat when there are multiple relationships for a given object of type A), and the values of the set are keys of type B.

Both would allow fast lookup when you have a key of type A, which is all I really need.

Using the single large sorted set seems maybe a bit less conventional to me, but it would clutter up the keyspace less, and it seems like it would work just as well.

Is there any big reason to do it one way or the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One large sorted set is harder to shard (should it grow too large for a single machine). Other than that, they both should work just fine.

I wouldn't worry too much about cluttering of keyspace. Redis can happily handle millions of keys (one of my servers has 30+ millions).